# ScrollView not Working - Relative Layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse, layout, scrollview

I am trying to wrap a realtive view in a scrollview as per the code below. However the problem is that the view doesn't scroll, even though part of the view is off the screen. I am testing this on the emulator.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroller"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:orientation="vertical"
> 
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/namedetail"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:typeface="sans" 
  />      
<ImageView android:id="@+id/picturedetail"
android:layout_width="175dip"
android:layout_height="175dip"
android:layout_below="@id/namedetail"
android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
/>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/infoboxdetail"
android:layout_width="225dip"
android:layout_height="100dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
android:layout_below="@id/picturedetail"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate"
/>
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/descriptiondetail"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundstate"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
android:layout_height="50dip"
android:textColor="#FF000000"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="15sp"
android:typeface="sans" 
android:layout_below="@id/infoboxdetail"
android:layout_marginTop ="10dip"
/>  
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

EDIT

OK solved - user stupidity - the bottom text box was off the screen on my monitor but not in the emulator. Making it longer makes it now scroll.

Comment: It seems to work for me. I opened it in a emulator with qvga. And it was scrolling. All i did to the code was replace your drawables with colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `RelativeLayout` is `horizontal` and you use a `ScrollView`, try a `HorizontalScrollView` instead.

Comment: sorry code was wrong - have corrected - the layout is vertical.

Comment: `RelativeLayout` has no field `orientation`. Only `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is because the `RelativeLayout` doesn't stretch based on content. The `ScrollView` will fill the screen and then the `RelativeLayout` will fill the `ScrollView`. The size of the `RelativeLayout` will not change as you put widgets into it.

I would try using another type of layout - perhaps a `TableLayout` og a combination of nested `LinearLayout`.

Is there any specific reason why you're using the `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: I think that's the problem. I have position everything though using layout_below etc commands so when I switch to linear it scrolls but everything is a mess :(

Comment: And I have elements overlapped - e.g a button on a white background.

Comment: Seeing as you put all the widgets below each other in a sequential order, there is no reason not to use a LinearLayout. As I stated a series of nested layouts will probably do the trick. On the other hand, all the widgets in your layout have a specific height so just set the height of the RelativeLayout to the sum of heights.

Comment: Just to add it is all working - so your comment about relative views not working in a scroll view is unfounded.