# Using RelativeLayout inside ScrollView doesn't yield in scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to get my relative layout to scroll. I added the scroll view as a parent but when I tilt the phone, or emulator to horizontal, it doesn't scroll.

I've tried a few different solutions but none of them seem to work.
Some include:
[No scrolling in scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7900842/no-scrolling-in-scrollview), [ScrollView not Working - Relative Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349022/scrollview-not-working-relative-layout), and [RelativeLayout with scrollview not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321063/relativelayout-with-scrollview-not-scrolling)

The code is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none">
<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp" 
            android:id="@+id/register_button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Register" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/register_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/register_button"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/register_button"
            android:hint="Re-Enter Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/email2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email2"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/email1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/email1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email1"
            android:hint="Repeat Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/password2"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password2"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/password1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/password1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/password1"
            android:hint="Last Name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lastName"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lastName"
            android:hint="First Name"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/firstName"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/firstName"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />




</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your `RelativeLayout` is set to `fill_parent`. If it's the same size as its `ScrollView` parent, there's nothing to scroll. Make it `wrap_content` instead and properly layout its children to imply a height.

Comment: I did that. I changed the relativelayout from fill parent to wrap_content. It throws everything to the left, and no scrolling. I changed scrollview to wrap content, and I can't realign the fields of the relativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

`android:fillViewport="true"`

add this line as your scroll view attribute :)